# How to move a Google Sheet from one file to another while retaining external references

Tags: google-sheets, regexextract

**Background**
I usually add several sheets to a single Google sheets file. There is always a separate sheet that extracts information from the other sheets (via `REGEXEXTRACT` etc).

**Problem**
sometimes this "summary" sheet has sensitive information in it that I don't want shared with everyone, and I would like to simply copy it and paste it into a different Google sheets file that's shared with a specific set of people. The problem is that if I simply make a copy and paste.. all the cells that references other cells get an error since they now reference cells that don't exist.. How do I handle this?

Comment: I'm downvoting this question as it doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try making refference using `inditect`:

transform this: `=RegexExtract(Sheet1!A1)` to this → `=RegexExtract(indirect("Sheet1!A1"))`

or better this → `=RegexExtract(indirect(B1))` and paste the name of range in B2.

When you'll copy the sheet to other books, you'll be able to correct value in `B2` to a new sheet refference.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

To convert local references to external references use IMPORTRANGE

## How

1. First you have to get the spreadsheet key / file id or the URL to the original spreadsheet
2. Wherever your sheet has a local reference that should be converted to an external reference, use IMPORTRANGE to convert it to an external reference

### Example

Change

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

to

```
=IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key,"Sheet1!A1")
```